# Django POST request issue with model

Tags: django

I have a model `Condition` that has a field `symptoms`, which takes multiple different `Symptoms` objects. Whenever, I make a POST request to create a Condition object, I get the following error:

> 'Condition: epilepsy' needs to have a value for field "condition" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

The above 'Condition: epilepsy' is nested between <>, but theres a formatting issue with posting that.

Here is my Condition model:

```
class Condition(models.Model):
class Treatment():
    SURGERY, NON_INVASIVE, PRESCRIPTION_MEDICINE, NONE = range(4)
    CHOICES = (
        (SURGERY, 'Surgery'),
        (NON_INVASIVE, 'Non-Invasive Treatment'),
        (PRESCRIPTION_MEDICINE, 'Prescription Medicine'),
        (NONE, 'None')
        )
class Medicalfield(models.Model):
    ONCOLOGY, CARDIOLOGY, NEPHROLOGY, PEDIATRICS, ENDOCRONOLOGY, PSYCHOLOGY = range(6)
    CHOICES = (
        (ONCOLOGY, 'Oncology'),
        (CARDIOLOGY, 'Cardiology'),
        (NEPHROLOGY, 'Nephrology'),
        (PEDIATRICS, 'Pediatrics'),
        (ENDOCRONOLOGY, 'Endocronology'),
        (PSYCHOLOGY, 'Psychology')
        )

name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
contagious = models.BooleanField()
treatable = models.BooleanField()
treatment = models.IntegerField(choices=Treatment.CHOICES, null=True)
severeity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
symptoms = models.ManyToManyField('Symptom', blank=True)
medicalfield = models.IntegerField(choices=Medicalfield.CHOICES, null=True)

new = ConditionManager()

def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s" % ( self.name )
```

Here is my Serializer

```
class ConditionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

def create(self, validated_data):
attrs = validated_data
request = self.context['request']
return Condition.new.create_condition(**attrs)

class Meta:
model = Condition
fields = ('id', 'treatment', 'name', 'contagious', 'treatable', 'treatment', 'severeity', 'symptoms', 'medicalfield')
```

Here is the Manager

```
class ConditionManager(models.Manager):
use_in_migrations = True
use_for_related_fields=True

def create_condition(self, *args, **kwargs):
    condition_obj = conditions.models.Condition(name=kwargs['name'], contagious=kwargs['contagious'], treatable=kwargs['treatable'], treatment=kwargs['treatment'], severeity=kwargs['severeity'], symptoms=kwargs['symptoms'], medicalfield=kwargs['medicalfield'])
    condition_obj.save()
    return condition_obj
```

And here is the View

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
def create_condition(request):
context = {'request': request}
symptoms = request.data['symptoms']
symptoms = Symptom.objects.filter(name__in=symptoms)
s = []
for symptom in symptoms:
    s.append(symptom.pk)
request.data['symptoms'] = s

serializer = ConditionSerializer(data=request.data, context=context)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    return response.Response(serializer.data, status=201)
return response.Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 477, in dispatch
response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 437, in handle_exception
self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 474, in dispatch
response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 52, in handler
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/medicalrecords/conditions/views.py", line 28, in create_condition
serializer.save()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 214, in save
self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
File "/Users/user/medicalrecords/conditions/serializers.py", line 24, in create
return Condition.new.create_condition(**attrs)
File "/Users/user/medicalrecords/conditions/managers.py", line 17, in create_condition
condition_obj = conditions.models.Condition(name=kwargs['name'], contagious=kwargs['contagious'], treatable=kwargs['treatable'], treatment=kwargs['treatment'], severeity=kwargs['severeity'], symptoms=kwargs['symptoms'], medicalfield=kwargs['medicalfield'])
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 550, in __init__
setattr(self, prop, kwargs[prop])
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 499, in __set__
manager = self.__get__(instance)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 476, in __get__
return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 783, in __init__
(instance, self.source_field_name))
ValueError: "<Condition: epilepsy>" needs to have a value for field "condition" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
[22/Feb/2017 20:01:45] "POST /conditions/new/condition/ HTTP/1.1" 500 15799
```

**traceback from @snakefcz 's answer**

> Internal Server Error: /conditions/new/condition/
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
>       return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
>       return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 477, in dispatch
>       response = self.handle_exception(exc)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 437, in handle_exception
>       self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 474, in dispatch
>       response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 52, in handler
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Users/user/medicalrecords/conditions/views.py", line 45, in create_condition
>       return response.Response(serializer.data, status=201)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 527, in data
>       ret = super(Serializer, self).data
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 262, in data
>       self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 496, in to_representation
>       ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 643, in to_representation
>       self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 479, in to_representation
>       fields = self._readable_fields
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in **get**
>       res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 373, in _readable_fields
>       field for field in self.fields.values()
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 359, in fields
>       for key, value in self.get_fields().items():
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 1010, in get_fields
>       fields[field_name] = field_class(**field_kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 733, in **init**
>       super(CharField, self).**init**(**kwargs)
>   TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'view_name'

Comment: You you post the full traceback, please?

Comment: added the traceback

Comment: you may need to add null=True for `symptom` column on your model.

Comment: where exactly should I put it? in the manager or in the serializer?

Comment: you have to save the data before saving m2m field data.

Comment: @SnakeFcz where do I save it? in the serializer or the view?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a `Symptom` serializer in addition to the `Condition` one. Your `ConditionSerializer` should look something like:

```
class ConditionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  symptoms = SymptomSerializer(read_only=True, many=True, allow_null=True)
  class Meta:
    model = Condition
    fields = ('id', 'treatment', 'name', 'contagious', 'treatable', 'treatment', 'severeity', 'symptoms', 'medicalfield')

  def create(self, validated_data):
    attrs = validated_data
    request = self.context['request']
    return Condition.new.create_condition(**attrs)
```

Comment: i just made the change, but now i'm getting an error with the manager:

Comment: condition_obj = conditions.models.Condition(name=kwargs['name'], contagious=kwargs['contagious'], treatable=kwargs['treatable'], treatment=kwargs['treatment'], severeity=kwargs['severeity'], symptoms=kwargs['symptoms'], medicalfield=kwargs['medicalfield'])
KeyError: 'symptoms'

Comment: I edited my answer to show what @Manjit Kumar said. It sounds like you're passing in an empty `symptoms` when you create your `Condition`. You should be checking to make sure your `kwargs` has the key or use the `.get()` method on it to define a default.

Answer (score 0):

```
## Try it 
@api_view(['POST'])
    @permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
    def create_condition(request):
        context = {'request': request}
        serializer = ConditionSerializer(data=request.data, context=context)
        if serializer.is_valid():
           condition = serializer.save()
           symptoms = request.data['symptoms']
           for symp in symptoms:
               symptom = Symptom.objects.get(id=symp) ## if it's id's you are passing
               condition.symptoms.add(symptom)

           return response.Response(serializer.data, status=201)
    return response.Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Comment: It's successfully creating the object, but its giving me a 500 error. I edited the question with the traceback